# Pyautogui locateOnScreen is not working if making size of UI is small by using maximize/restore button

Tags: python, pyautogui

I ran my GUI and taken an image screenshot using the code (UI is maximized).

```
im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(23,110, 50, 20))
im.save("general.png")
```

Now I run again to search the image.

```
pyautogui.getWindow('my window title')
time.sleep(5)
button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('general.png')
button7x, button7y = pyautogui.center(button7location)
pyautogui.click(button7x, button7y)
```

It is able to locate if UI size if maximize but if I am making UI size a bit small it is returning None.

Which means I always have to give correct pixel to use `pyautogui.click(button7x, button7y)` which I would like to avoid.
Could someone let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Pyautogui scans for the exact image pixel by pixel from the window screen. So, you cannot expect it to execute while resizing the UI.